# iOS Camera overlay transparency issue

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay

I am adding a custom view overlay in `UIImagePickerController` like so:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.myToolbar];
```

The result is as below:

[image]

The issue is that the overlay is not opaque. It definitely used to be in older versions of iOS, but the new version (screenshot using iOS 10) somehow applies transparency to the overlay.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: try to add the toolbar on UIImagePickerController view

Comment: That's what I did, I added it to `self.view` inside of `UIImagePickerController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Objective C**

Set `isTranslucent` of `UIToolBar` to `false`

```
self.myToolbar.translucent = false;
```

if you want to disable transparency of `UIToolBar` throughout the app add the following code in app `delegate` `didFinishLaunch` function

```
 [UIToolbar appearance].translucent = false;
```

**In Swift 3**

Set `isTranslucent` of `UIToolBar` to `false`

```
self.myToolbar.isTranslucent = false
```

if you want to disable transparency of `UIToolBar` throughout the app add the following code in app `delegate` `didFinishLaunch` function

```
 UIToolbar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: Great, thank you, this worked. Only I had to use `self.myToolbar.translucent = false` as `isTranslucent` is a getter.